# OOM out of memory android error while heap has lots of space

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Unless I'm reading the below incorrectly this allocation should be absolutely fine?

The DDMS shows a

```
Heap size 15.3 Mb
Allocated 8.211 Mb
Free      7.11 Mb
```

I've run a dump through MAT (I'm not very familiar with) but shows the same

Debug below:

> E/dalvikvm-heap(6989): 1536000-byte external allocation too large for
>   this process. E/dalvikvm(6989): Out of memory: Heap Size=15687KB,
>   Allocated=10710KB, Bitmap Size=8845KB E/GraphicsJNI(6989): VM won't
>   let us allocate 1536000 bytes

Please can anyone explain? It's driving me crazy?

Comment: Which is the allocation?

Comment: Not sure if this is entirely relevant but which version of android are you testing this on? Before 3.0, bitmaps are stored externally. This means whilst they contribute to the overall application memory limit, they are not actually stored on the dalvik heap. This means the memory used by these bitmaps will not show up on DDMS or MAT.

Comment: Every time I decode or create the bitmaps they are 1536000 bytes getRowBytes() * getHeight()

Comment: @Wozza 2.3.5 I knew that about DDMS, not MAT.

Comment: I bm.recycle after all use and have sprinkled System.gc liberally, still getting OOM though

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image and what is the heap space limit for the device/emulator?

Comment: So is Bitmap Size saying that that is the TOTAL allocation of bitmap memory? So added with the allocated app is over the heap limit? Is there a way of monitoring or outputting this value manually?

Comment: @Wozza  Heap Size=15687KB image is a bitmap of a screen capture on a HTC desire

Comment: I've started querying nativeHeapFreeSize: on Samsung Galaxy S1 and S2 which depletes on successive calls until a bottom level where it stays indefinitely. On the Desire it keeps falling till it throws an OOM?